# Exibir resto dos dados do BD mysqli em nova janela em PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

Bom o que eu gostaria de fazer é chamar os dados do banco de dados para serem exibidos apenas os dados principais em uma tabela, e, nessa mesma tabela ter o botão visualizar onde quanto eu o apertar ele abre uma janela com o resto das informações do banco de dados.
A parte de exibir as principais informações eu já fiz, mas não sei como fazer com que ele abra outra janela e exiba o resto das informações daquele id.

Essa é a tabela que aparece as informações do BD ja com o botao para abrir outra janela com o resto das informaçoes do BD:

[image: Tabela de Exibição]]

Essa é a parte do codigo que exibe as informaçoes:

[image: Codigo DA tabela]

Comment: Coloque seu código não imagens.

Comment: Já tentou usar `target="_blank"`no `</a>` e no `href` passar o id via GET?

Comment: Mas vc quer abrir uma janela popup ou uma nova aba?

Comment: Ficaria mais interessante abrir uma modal e puxar os dados via Ajax.

Comment: Se você quer ajuda e uma resposta para seu problema, ao invés de postar imagens post o código para que possamos copiar, fazer testes e apresentar uma solução. Qualquer duvida leia esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Answer (score 1):

Você pode abrir uma nova guia usando `<a target="_blank" ...` passando o id pela url e recuperando com `$_GET`:

```
<a href="detalhes.php?id=<?php echo $f["idEmulador"]; ?>" target="_blank">
    <button class="button">Expandir</button>
</a>
```

Na página de detalhes:

```
<?php 
$idEmulador = $_GET["id"];

//Realiza a busca pelo id e mostra ...
```

Uma dica de design, no lugar do button você pode usar um ícone do tipo:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="material-icons">visibility</i>
<i class="material-icons">edit</i>
```